# WOrdpress- woocommerce - email order or invoice email : how to edit css style?

Tags: css, email, woocommerce, editing

Editing CSS of woocommerce shop its okay.

But what about the email woocommerce send? Firebug useless since email once sent belongs to yahoo or gmail  or...

trying [this hooks](http://www.grapekiwi.ca/how-to-edit-the-css-of-a-woocommerce-email-template/) doesn't work : my new h3 (for exemple) font size rule is recognized but a element.style from i don't know where has priority and maintain h" font size to 30 px.

I'm lost, what's the right way to change CSS of it?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Or you Can try this filter by placing on your theme's function.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_styles', 'mmr_woocommerce_email_styles' );
function mmr_woocommerce_email_styles( $css ) {
    $css .= "#header_wrapper {    padding: 20px 48px; }";
    $css .= "#header_wrapper h1 { font-size:20px; }";
    return $css;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By overriding the woocommerce theme components: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the woo commerce email template by copying the relevant email into your theme.

Example: To overide the admin order notification, copy: woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php

You then can edit the email template in the new location. The CSS that governs the email is hard coded in the template, so open it in a text editor and change it there. Also have a look at the header and footer templates if you want to change the appearance of those areas of the email.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The CSS is separate from the HTML for the e-mail. Before the e-mail is sent, Woocommerce actually inlines the CSS using the Emogrifier library. Using the `woocommerce_email_styles` filter to add new CSS to the e-mails ensures that your new CSS is inlined into the generated HTML. This prevents issues with clients like Gmail, which remove a lot of stylesheets from HTML emails.